Why fwrite writes an excessive byte 00 at the first byte of file?
I wrote this piece of code :
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE * fp;
    int num[100];
    int number;

    fp = fopen("myfile.bin", "wb");
    
    for (number = 0; number < 100; ++number)
    {
        num[number] = number;
    }
    fwrite(num, 4, 100, fp);
    
    fclose(fp);
    
    return 0;
}

And fwrite writes down an excessive byte by value 00 in the first byte of file:
00 00 00 00 01

An int is only 4 bytes and the other bytes write normally but the first one, not.
What's wrong here? I tested by GCC, Clang and TCC, and read the file with Bless and Ghex. Same results.
I'm on Intel Pentium G3220, Debian GNU/Linux 12.5 and using GCC 12.2.0-3.

Your example of what is going on does not make sense. You have six bytes listed there, which is not a remainder of four. Is that exactly what you see when using od?

You... aren’t counting the initial offset column in the output of od, are you?

"An int is only 4 bytes" - are you assuming that, or did you verify it? Why not use sizeof(int) instead?

You're probably displaying your hex dump per word, rather than per byte and your system is little endian. On my machine hexdump will produce "00 00 00 00" "00 01 00 00" with the -x flag and "00 00 00 00" "01 00 00 00" with the -C flag.

@Dúthomhas I wrote 1 byte excessive , It's 5 bytes . And I explained clearly , Even using char and starting from 1 , One byte by 00 as Hex is written excessively

@RemyLebeau I have Intel Pentium G3220 64 bit and size of int is 4 bytes ; Even I change the 4 to sizeof(int) doesn't change the excessive FIRST byte

@HadiLovelorn If you do ls -l myfile.bin do you get 400 or 401 bytes?

@HadiLovelorn, when done, what is the file's entire length?

"What's wrong here ? " --> debug is incorrect.

What do you see if you instead use num[number] = 0x7fffff00 + number;?

@Loocid I get 400 ; I wrote from 0 to 99 but fwrite(num, 4, 100, fp) useless 00 bytes are written at the end of file ... But the first byte is excessive and shouldn't be 5 bytes to write 1 ... The rest are true and only take 4 bytes

Also, delete the file before running (it may be writing somewhere else depending on how you're running it). And check the return values from fopen/fwrite/etc.

@paxdiablo Still getting first byte as excessive : 00 FF FF 7F 01 , the rest is ok and works well just like before

Can't reproduce on my Intel Xeon

@HadiLovelorn That's not an excessive byte, that's just little endian.

That first byte is not excessive, 00 ff ff 7f is the little-endian representation of the first number, the next four would be 01 ff ff 7f. Are you absolutely sure that your original was 00 00 00 00 00 01 and not 00 00 00 00 01? The latter would also be correct as the full zero value and least significant byte of one.

@paxdiablo I deleted the file , The bug still exist . I printed how many fwrite returns and it shows 100

I don't know how you display the file but could that "extra" 00 be the offset ? hexdump -C display the offset on each line like 00000000  00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00  02 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 but uses 4 bytes for offset. So the next line is 00000010  04 00 00 00 05 00 00 00  06 00 00 00 07 00 00 00

@paxdiablo It will display 00 00 00 00 00 01 if the bytes are grouped by word, which would explain what OP is seeing (eg the default hexdump output).

That's NOT an extra byte that is 00 00 00 00 ZERO. It's little-endian, your 1 starts at offset 0x04 in the file... E.G. for (number = 0; number < 100; ++number) If you want 1 - 100, then do for (number = 0; number < 100; ++number) { num[number] = number + 1; }

@paxdiablo But sir , See it Yourself : https://ibb.co/5T5h9Hg I write down from 1 to 99 and all the numbers are ok and take 4 bytes .... But the first byte is excessive and useless and shouldn't be write

No, your first number is zero, not one. That's the 00 00 00 00. The next number (one) is 01 00 00 00 . That's what little-endian is.

@HadiLovelorn That screenshot shows 00 00 00 00 which is 0, then 01 00 00 00 which is 1. The output is correct.

No one can reproduce this: op claims libc is failing here. It absolutely is not. Besides claims to what he has or hasn't done and still being vague about exactly how he is getting he view of the data, etc, this is a problem between the user and the keyboard. The code in the Q does not produce extra unwanted bytes

We've all been there, it's just a CRI, the light-bulb will wink on shortly....

The picture shows correct output. You are just reading it wrong. Change your program and start with 5 instead of 0. The read about endianess. The first 00 00 00 00 is the decimal value zero. Then 01 00 00 00 is decimal value one. Then 02 00 00 00 is decimal value two. And so on. All is good

@SupportUkraine and other gentlemen Ok , You are right . But I started from 1 why it shows 0 ?

BTW: Kind of strange that your "hex editor" shows 31 bytes per line but maybe it depends on windows size (?)

You didn't start from one, you started from zero. You set number initially to zero and the ++number happens after the loop body.

number = 0;  is starting from zero

Trust me, you are going to get it. Just ask yourself, on the first iteration through the loop when number == 0, what is the value of num[0], e.g.  num[number] = number; which you then write as your first value to the file??

@SupportUkraine and other gentlemen , I changed it to 1 and still the same bug exist . ( and the step level pre increase the 0 to 1 but I changed it to ensure )

All you need to change is num[number] = number + 1; don't change anything else. This will fix it -- I promise...

@DavidC.Rankin I did it and it works , But why should this happen ?

Think about it. When you enter your loop, for (number = 0; number < 100; ++number) the first time though the loop number is equal to ZERO. When you assign num[number] = number; you assign ZERO to the first element of the num[] array. ZERO is an ordinary int and it takes 4-bytes to store (all zeros of course). When you write your array to the file with fwrite() the first element of num[] (e.g. the first 4-bytes) are written to the file as 00 00 00 00. That is exactly what you see. The next 4-bytes for 1 are written next 01 00 00 00. Exactly what you see. You'll get it.

You seem to be reading the file wrongly. The hex output:
00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 ...

is little endian (where the higher memory addresses carry the more significant parts of the value), with four bytes per integer:

00 00 00 00 = 0.
01 00 00 00 = 1.
02 00 00 00 = 2.
and so on ...

You seem to think it's:
00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 03 ...
?? |    1    | |    2    | |    3    |

with an extraneous byte at the start but that is not the case. The fact that you have a four-hundred-byte file after writing one hundred four-byte integers should make that clear.
The final four bytes will be, in your case, 63 00 00 00 and that's a little-endian 99, not 100. Your comment that you're starting with one is incorrect, the loop executes the body with values 0..99 inclusive:
for (number = 0; number < 100; ++number) {
    num[number] = number;
}

C arrays are zero-based, not one-based, so 0..99 are the correct indexes for a 100-element array (and also the values that you are storing). If you do desire to store 1..100 inclusive in your array, you could instead use:
for (number = 0; number < 100; ++number) {
    num[number] = number + 1;
}

The indexes are still 0..99 but the values are now 1..100.

"OP doesn't understand what some tools said about the file contents, while asking about the code that created the file" is a textbook example of "caused by a typo or not reproducible" - OP is claiming the existence of a problem that isn't actually there. (If you inferred a question like "how do I properly interpret the output of bless?", then that wouldn't be an on-topic question, nor a clear (directly asked) one. Please read: Why should I help close "bad" questions that I think are valid, instead of helping the OP with an answer?

(OP seems to have quite deliberately written five leading zero bytes in describing the output rather than four, and insisted on this point. If you believe regardless that the conceptual issue is with understanding endianness, then surely there's a duplicate for that instead.)

Tthank YOu ... But read the comments ; Why it starts from 0 ? Even if I start num from 1 ?

@Karl: I've had this discussion here before; in fact I think it was specifically with you as I recognise the "stepping back" in your bio. And, as stated, the "swarm" decides the value of a question/answer, not any individual member. My own purpose here is mainly to educate so, while you can work to convince me, the bar for a "bad" question is possibly set higher for me that for you. That's probably because I assign more importance to the help center (don't ask) than meta.

@Karl: In any case, the question has been closed (by the swarm) and may well end up being deleted at some point so it's working as intended. My purpose will hopefully have been served in the meantime.

@HadiLovelorn: see the updated answer, it starts from zero because that's what you told it to do. Arrays in C are zero-based so your 100-element array uses the indexes 0..99 inclusive.

Thank You , Sir .... Sorry for late , The topic was locked and I earned some privileges .... You point the problem
